# How much a site collection can store if i do not specify any Qoute when creating it

Tags: 2013, site-collection, administration, content-database

I am working on an on-premise sharepoint enterprise server 2013. currently i have the following info:-

1. i have one web application + one content database.
2. I have 10 site collections.

now when i create my site collections i always specify not to have any Quota, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce if there are any limitation about the size of each of the site collections?  or since i did not specify any Quota for the site collections,, so each site collection can have dynamic maximum size as long as the database server have space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sizing information can be found on [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Limits and boundaries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Limits%20and%20boundaries)

A site collection has no specific size limitation, but a single content database is limited to **200GB** in general usage scenarios, and **4TB** absolute maximum.

It is however recommended to keep the site collection size under 100GB

> A site collection can be as large as the content database size limit
> for the applicable usage scenario. For more information about the
> different content database size limits for specific usage scenarios,
> see the Content database limits table in this article. In general, we
> strongly recommend limiting the size of site collections to 100 GB for
> the following reasons:
>
> - Certain site collection actions, such as site
>   collection backup/restore or the Windows PowerShell cmdlet
>   Move-SPSite, cause large SQL Server operations which can affect
>   performance or fail if other site collections are active in the same
>   database. For more information, see Move-SPSite.
> - SharePoint site collection backup and restore is only supported for a maximum site
>   collection size of 100 GB. For larger site collections, the complete
>   content database must be backed up. If multiple site collections
>   larger than 100 GB are contained in a single content database, backup
>   and restore operations can take a long time and are at risk of
>   failure.

Comment: so seems the site collection can hold as much as the content DB can hold... but Microsoft does not recommend to extend the size of a site collection to more than 100GB because backup/restore site collection will not longer be supported, and we will have to backup the whole content database and can not backup single site collections... is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG this seems to be correct indeed. (edited my answer to elaborate)
however, nothing is stopping you from separating content DB's for your site collections, which might be useful for backup/restore scenarios

Comment: but not sure what do you exactly mean by "however, nothing is stopping you from separating content DB's for your site collections, which might be useful for backup/restore scenarios " ??

Comment: You can create multiple content databases, which can each hold 1 or more site collections. To avoid backup/restore issues, it might be useful to limit the content databases to hold MAX 1 site collection - so when restoring of a site collection is needed, this can easily be done by restoring the relevant content database

Comment: so you mean to have one web application, and then inside the web application to create separate content database for each site collection ?? but will this affect storage utilization??

Comment: Only very little. Storage is 99% relative to usage of your site collection (document size, ...).